# WPF Choppy / Jerky Animation

Tags: wpf

I am starting to work in WPF and I have found that animation is slow and jerky on my PC. I am running Windows XP Pro SP3 and have the latest gpu drivers (Quadro FX 1800), direct x 9 build and .net 3.5 versions.

I am at a loss as to whats going on as there are two other identical PCs in the office, one of which has the same problems as me, the other runs fine.

The code I am running is the animation sample code from Kaxami, but running as a compiled app in VS 2008:

http://pastebin.com/zU7zvCB5 (couldn't get the XAML in)

So I am quite at a loss.

Anyone have any similar problems, or things I should compare between the working PC and the non working PC in terms of software versions?

Thanks

Comment: We have discovered that the demo app runs fine when the processor on the machine is taxed by another appliction to 100%. For example if we do a hard drive search (just to use CPU) the wpf application runs smooth as silk.

Answer (score -1):

WPF is single-buffered on XP, that may be the problem. MS wants you to buy Vista or Seven.

Comment: But how can we think of developing a WPF application if it won't work on a lot of our client PC's. There must be a better answer than this as else it would fail on all windows xp machines we test it on, one works. Another XP PC in the office which has a different config also works.

Comment: Well, don't know then. Try WPF Performance Suite (if not already), maybe you notice something strange there.

Comment: THanks, but the WPS seems to only work on Windows 7 configurations.

Comment: I have it installed on XP box... there must be XP version somewhere.

Comment: WPF is not single buffered on XP. I have done WPF development on XP and single buffered looks different.